# undefined reference to 'FileReader :: FileReader()'

Tags: c++

Could anyone please help me fix my code so I can compile it.

When I compile it an error message "undefined reference to 'FileReader :: FileReader()'" comes up.

```
#ifndef SUBFILEREADER_H 
#define SUBFILEREADER_H
#include <string>
#include "FileReader.h"

using namespace std;

class SubFileReader : public FileReader
{
    string sS;
    int iS;
    string sHoldS;
    string siS;

public: 
    SubFileReader();
    string readFile(string file);
};
#endif
```

---

```
#include "SubFileReader.h"
#include "FileReader.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

/**
 * class SubFileReader, reads a file and prints it to stdout.
 * 
 * @author Alvin Benedicto
 * @version 2.12.10
 */
SubFileReader::SubFileReader() : FileReader()
{
    sS = "asdf";
    iS = 0;
    siS = "";
}

/**
 * readFile, reads the content of the file into a string and prints the string to standard output.
 * @ param file, string file to be read.
 */
string SubFileReader::readFile(string file)
{
    stringstream ints;

    ifstream in(file.c_str());
    while(getline(in, sS))
    {
        ints << iS++;
        ints >> siS;

        sHoldS += sS + " " + siS + "\n";
    }
    return sS;
}
```

---

```
#include "SubFileReader.h"
#include "FileReader.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/**
 * main, to test the methods
 * @author Alvin Benedicto
 * @version 2.12.10
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    string str;
    SubFileReader *yz = new SubFileReader();
    str = argv[1];

    ofstream out("MainSubFileReaderTest.txt");
    //cout << xy->readFile(str) << endl;
    out << yz->readFile(str);
}
```

Comment: Could you show us FileReader.h and .cpp ?

Comment: Please format it using code button. I would have edited only if I have enough reputation.

Comment: The command you're using to compile might help, as this sounds more like a compile issue than a code issue.

Answer (score 3):

You need to either compile FileReader.cpp, or link to whichever library contains the definition of `FileReader::FileReader()`.

Incidentally, you don't need to `#include` FileReader.h in your client code.

Comment: Actually the filereader class works fine. I'm just having probem compiling the subclass.

Comment: But are you telling the compiler where to find FileReader?  That's the "or link to whichever library..." part of this answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it compiles now.